# How can i assign every iteration of this while loop to a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

This `while` loop has long time in response time, thus I try that assign every iteration of this to a thread but I don't know what?
plz answer to me:(

```
string tmp = fr.getNextWord();

while (tmp != "")
{

    hf << h->getHash(tmp) << endl;        
    ENFA * enfa = new ENFA();
    * enfa = generateNfaFromString("%s%a_l%a%m%");
    if (enfa->accepts(h->getHash(tmp), getHashChar))
    {
        of << "true" << endl;
    } else 
    {
        of << "false" << endl;
    }
    tmp = fr.getNextWord(); 
}
```

Comment: Creating lots of threads is more likely going to slow things down as the cost of creating the thread is quite high in comparison to functions like `getHash()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Refactor the contents of the loop into a separate function call.
2. Create a container of thread objects (preferably wrapped in a future object) outside the loop.
3. Within the loop, create a new thread that calls the function. Store the thread object (or the associated future) in the container.
4. (optional: Scratch your head and wonder why the response time became worse)

Comment: I would consider that advice now outdated now that we have `async()`. Which should handle all the threading for you.

Comment: @LokiAstari I inteded the advice to be higher level than that. It doesn't matter if the thread (object) is wrapped within a a future; the steps in the answer will be the same. Of course, a structured approach would be better than bare threads.

Comment: the accept() function is NFA pattern matching and have about 10 min in response time!!! thus i want to assigned each matching to a thread ! is that right?

Comment: @r.hg how many cpu cores does the processor that you run on have? How many iterations do you tend to need? Do they have a lot of output?

Comment: this code will run in cloud server thus have appropriate hardware.
 the number of iterations depends on the input text file lines.
Actually this code is matching regular expression in encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can store all words in `fr` in a `std::vector`, you can try to use [`openmp`](http://openmp.org/wp/)

```
std::vector<string> v;
//TODO: loop over `fr` and push_back the words onto `v`

# pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    //use `v[i]` instead of `tmp` in your code
}
```